# ng-click for a reset button only works once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, reset

I am having an issue with a reset button. It works, but only once. After that I need to reload the webpage to get the button to work again.

In JS file

```
var ctrl = this;
var original_device = angular.copy(device.data);
ctrl.device = device.data;

ctrl.reset = function () {
    ctrl.device = original_device;
};
```

In html file

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.reset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by work only once?

Comment: I mean it only resets the values one time. After that it does not reset values.

Comment: plnkr.co is the best I can do to provide the full code for these two files I mentioned. Here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/vCkgQjtFuPltBTn5oviK?p=preview

Comment: Update: I found a fix. I made a second deep copy of the variable I am trying to reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to copy the copy because after you use it, device and the copy will be the same object.

```
ctrl.reset = function () {
     ctrl.device = angular.copy(original_device);
};
```

Comment: @epascarello This doesn't work. I threw the code into plnkr.co since it works with angular. here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/vCkgQjtFuPltBTn5oviK?p=preview